# Extra Braces When \url Uses Variable

Tags: macros, hyperref, urls, csname

When using `\url{}` in the following example, it adds additional braces around the variable. So the code below renders:

{google.com} - google.com

1. Why is this happening, how can I avoid it?
2. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do here?
   I want to have one command (`\template`) that will take some arguments at one place in the file or in another file and the other command (`\render`) that is responsible for how those arguments will be shown (rendered). I want to easily add/remove arguments from the `\template` command. I want to be able to use `\template` and `\render` multiple times by specifying and then referencing the first variable passed to `\template` eg. using *tex_url* in the same way as *google_url*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{forarray}

\newcommand{\template}[2]{
\DefineArrayVar{#1}{@}
{|}{URL}
{|}{{#2}}
}

\newcommand{\render}[1]{
  \subheading{\csname #1@URL\endcsname}
}

\newcommand{\subheading}[1]{
    \url{#1} - #1
}

\begin{document}
    \template{google_url}{google.com}
    \render{google_url}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the code errors.

Comment: Yes, it did, sorry about that. I had a typo.

Comment: You have an extra set of braces around `#2` in your definition of `\template`; getting rid of them seems to work. Was there a reason why they were there? Does anything break if you get rid of them?

Comment: @bonk you are right, it works now, thank you. I had more than one parameter there and I was convinced that I needed braces around them, but you don't.
So if you want to have additional parameters you can do this:

`\newcommand{\template}[4]{
\DefineArrayVar{#1}{@}
{|}{URL|foo|bar}
{|}{#2|#3|#4}
}`

I would like to upvote your comment or something, but I think I can't. It is correct though, thanks once again :)

Also, `/url` and `/href` were the only functions that caught this mistake. Other functions just didn't render extra braces for some reason.